# Узнать поведение функции toFixed

Tags: javascript

Изучая JS наткнулся на пример:

```
function getDecimal(num) {
  return +(num % 1).toFixed(6);
}

alert( getDecimal(1.2) ); // 0.2
alert( getDecimal(1.3) ); // 0.3 
alert( getDecimal(1.4) ); // 0.4
```

в комемнтариях в конце строк указаны выводимые значения. А вот мой код и то что он выводит:

```
function getDecimal(num) {
  num = (num - Math.floor(num)).toFixed(6);
  alert(num);
}

alert( getDecimal(1.2) ); // 0.200000
alert( getDecimal(1.3) ); // 0.300000
alert( getDecimal(1.4) ); // 0.400000
```

Почему так?

Comment: Господа, почему-то код отобразился криво и html теги вывелись в строчку, хотя в предварительном просмотре все было отформатировано нормально.

Comment: используйте кнопочку **{}** вместо `pre` , это markdown

Comment: спасибо, так гораздо лучше!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что информацию надо брать в [документации](http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.7.html#x15.7.4.5) а не в примерах:

> > 15.7.4.5 Number.prototype.toFixed (fractionDigits) # Ⓣ Ⓡ
> > Возвращает **строку**, содержащую текущее числовое значение в десятичном представлении с фиксированной запятой, с цифрами после десятичной запятой в количество fractionDigits.

ну и в вашем случае приведите к числу :)

```
function getDecimal(num) {
  return +(num - Math.floor(num)).toFixed(6);
}
```

фишка примера в том, что toFixed округляет до 6го знака, а + приводит к типу число вместо строки.

Comment: Спасибо, невнимательность меня подвела